# What does it mean to "seal a block"?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, consensus, blocks

In both the Ethereum chain specification format and in Parity's documents on private chains,  you see the term `seal a block`.  What exactly does that term mean?  How is it different than mining a block?

Comment: No freaking idea but: "libethashseal: generic wrapper around the POW block seal engine" http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/what-are-the-modules.html?highlight=seal

Answer (score 11):

"Seal a block" is a [proposed term](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Chain-Spec-Format) to describe "mine a block" in a private chain.  Private chains typically do not need to use proof-of-work mining, so a different term can be helpful.  Specifics of what sealing means is up to a "seal engine", which is a proposed term to describe the consensus algorithm for a blockchain: one could describe that Ethereum currently uses a seal engine of Ethash, and has plans in the future to change the engine to Casper.

Answer (score 4):

**Sealing is the generic term for mining for the core devs**
I've asked the research slack and this was the answer:

> Hi, What does it mean "to seal" a block? is this different than
>   mining? E.g.: "libethashseal: generic wrapper around the POW block
>   seal engine. "
>   http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/what-are-the-modules.html?highlight=seal
>
> Eth-Gitter-Bridge @Eth-Gitter-Bridge 13:51 [Christian R] rolandkofler:
>   It is the more generic term

Comment: So what is a pre-sealed block?