# What is the difference between sealing and mining a block?

Tags: mining, evm

I have seen numerous sites referring to sealing a block and mining a block. I understand a miner seals a block but I do not really understand what sealing actually involves.

On that point, how does the VM actually know that a miner was 'first' in PoW consensus algorithms?

I assume a miner could just fake a response and listening on the network and then taking the correct answer and presenting that as the miner's own one.

The VM must have a means of controlling this.

On another related issue, the question of validation has come up. Is a validator a miner in a PoW based network?

Comment: possible duplicate  - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/what-does-it-mean-to-seal-a-block

Answer (score 2):

Sealing and mining and minting are the same term that indicates the action of creating new block in blockchain.

- Mining: Using in PoW consensus.
- Sealing: Using in PoA consensus.
- Minting: Using in PoS consensus.

If a block that were created in the way is not following the consensus it would be rejected by the consensus.